# how to add a click listener to different buttons using their id's

Tags: javascript

i have this arrow function displayExtraUserInfo with a single parameter and i want to Add a click listener to a BUTTON with id of btn-birthdate. The listener should make a call to displayBirthdate another function outside this function and pass in the parameter displayExtraUserInfo received.

```
const displayExtraUserInfo = (inputData) => {

  const button1 = document.getElementById("btn-birthdate");
  button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayBirthdate(inputData)
  });

  const button2 = document.getElementById("btn-phone");
  button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayPhone(inputData)
  });

  const button3 = document.getElementById("btn-address");
  button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayAddress(inputData)
  });

};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Please elaborate.

Comment: you're declaring `button1`, `button2` and `button3` but you're binding event 3 times on the `button1`

Answer (score 0):

Below code contains two objects with phone, address and birthdate.

When you click **Jack** button the below three buttons will display Jack's information  on click.

If you click **Charlie**, the buttons will display Charlie's information on click.

Here is a working example:

```js
function displayName(inputData){
document.getElementById("nameSpan").innerHTML = inputData.name
}

function displayBirthdate(inputData){
document.getElementById("bdSpan").innerHTML = inputData.birthDate
}

function displayPhone(inputData){
document.getElementById("phoneSpan").innerHTML = inputData.phone
}

function displayAddress(inputData){
document.getElementById("addressSpan").innerHTML = inputData.address
}

const displayExtraUserInfo = (inputData) => {
const button1 = document.getElementById("btn-name");
button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayName(inputData)
});

const button2 = document.getElementById("btn-birthdate");
button2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayBirthdate(inputData)
});

const button3 = document.getElementById("btn-phone");
button3.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayPhone(inputData)
});

const button4 = document.getElementById("btn-address");
button4.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayAddress(inputData)
});

document.getElementById("nameSpan").innerHTML=""
document.getElementById("bdSpan").innerHTML=""
document.getElementById("phoneSpan").innerHTML=""
document.getElementById("addressSpan").innerHTML=""
};



var jack = {
name: "Jack",
address: "Finland",
phone: "123456789",
birthDate: "20/10/1987"
}

var charlie = {
name: "Charlie",
address: "London",
phone: "0987654",
birthDate: "20/11/2001"
}

document.getElementById("btn-jack").addEventListener("click", function () {
displayExtraUserInfo(jack)
});

document.getElementById("btn-charlie").addEventListener("click", function () {
displayExtraUserInfo(charlie)
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-jack">Jack</button><br/>
<button id="btn-charlie">Charlie</button><br/>

<hr/>

<button id="btn-name">Name</button>  <button id="btn-birthdate">Birthdate</button> 
<button id="btn-phone">phone</button> <button id="btn-address">address</button>
<hr/>
<span>Name: </span><span id="nameSpan"></span><br/>
<span>Birthdate: </span><span id="bdSpan"></span><br/>
<span>Phone: </span><span id="phoneSpan"></span><br/>
<span>Address: </span><span id="addressSpan"></span><br/>
```

---

Edit: In your sample code you are assigning the event to button1 three times. If that is only a typo in the sample and not in your actual code base, then you should provide your code.

Comment: Please use the local snippet tool and avoid off-site links when you can.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question, it's not about an id per user.

Comment: My answer is not 'id per user'. With different buttons different users are being set to the context, and then the second level buttons enable displaying their properties.

Comment: Those kind of errors is considered as typo's, and for typo's we don't post answers, we use SO's built-in "vote/flag to close as typographical error" as they have no real value for future users.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was helpful then?

Answer (score 0):

As say on comment, your error came from you're declaring button1, button2 and button3 but you're binding event 3 times on the button1.

This should works fine.

```
const displayExtraUserInfo = (inputData) => {

  const button1 = document.getElementById("btn-birthdate");
  button1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayBirthdate(inputData)
  });

  const button2 = document.getElementById("btn-phone");
  button2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayPhone(inputData)
  });

  const button3 = document.getElementById("btn-address");
  button3.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayAddress(inputData)
  });

};
```

This is a dynamic and completed example of your needs.

```js
/* Declare */
const displayBirthdate = (inputData) => {
  console.log("displayBirthdate :", inputData)
}
const displayPhone = (inputData) => {
  console.log("displayPhone :", inputData)
}
const displayAddress = (inputData) => {
  console.log("displayAddress :", inputData)
}

/* Setup events */
const displayExtraUserInfo = (inputData) => {
  const fns = [
   {id: 'btn-birthdate', fn: displayBirthdate},
   {id: 'btn-phone', fn: displayPhone},
   {id: 'btn-address', fn: displayAddress},
  ]
  
  fns.forEach(el => {
    let btn = document.getElementById(el.id)
    btn && btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      el.fn(inputData)
    })
  })
};

/* Init */
displayExtraUserInfo({foo:"bar"})
```

```html
<button id="btn-birthdate">Birthday</button><button id="btn-phone">Phone</button>
```

Comment: Those kind of errors is considered as typo's, and for typo's we don't post answers, we use SO's built-in "vote/flag to close as typographical error" as they have no real value for future users.

Comment: @LGSon I agree, and I already post a comment for the typo, I just reply here to add a solution to build relation between id and function to call on click (like requested on question) but witout copy/pasting code.